# Should there be one device provisioning service for one IoT hub if it is associated with one tenant?

Tags: security, azure, provisioning

I have a multi-tenancy situation where I have created one IoT hub per tenant.

Now if I have 5 tenants, and I create 5 Iot hub, should I also create 5 device provisioning service for those 5 IoT hubs (one for each)?
So that when I onboard devices on a large scale I can programmatically add provision configuration in the app (I will be creating 5 apps for 5 tenants because each tenant's requirements will be different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a single Device Provsioning Service (DPS) instance is enough to handle this scenario. All I have to consider is the attestation mechanism, in order to identify the devices to DPS. An intermediate certificate of the tenant can be uploaded in the DPS enrollment list and the same certificate will be used for signing the device certificates which belong to that tenant.

So even if the application of each tenant is different I need to have common properties of DPS encoded in the device during manufacturing/factory setup process so that on internet connection available it can start first communication to DPS to get the specific IoT Hub information, which will be available in the enrollment list of the tenant.